# How to test upload file using Postman or Any HTTP Request Simulator

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, kendo-ui, wsdl

I have RESTful WSDL service to upload a file(Image) on the server, I don't' know how to consume this web service using Swift, Java or at least on Postman.

Below the Service on .NET WSDL File

```
<xs:element name="SaveFile">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element xmlns:q24="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message" name="stream" type="q24:StreamBody"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Ther Service owner use Kendo to consume the serive and upload Images/PDF.

below Kendo that consume the service:

```
function InitiateFileUpload(fileType, multiple, extensions) {


        var fileInput = $("#fileAttachment-" + fileType);
        var errorMessagelbl = $("#errorAttachmentMessages-" + fileType);

        fileInput.kendoUpload({
            multiple: multiple,
            async: {

                saveUrl: serviceAnonymousURL + 'SaveFile',
                removeUrl: serviceAnonymousURL + 'RemoveFile',
                autoUpload: false
            },
            template: kendo.template($('#fileTemplate').html()),
            upload: function (e) {
                e.data = {
                    userName: $("#hdnLoginId").val(),
                    fileName: $("#hdnName" + e.files[0].uid).val(),
                    fileId: e.files[0].uid,
                    fileType: fileType
                };
            },
            remove: function (e) {
                RemoveFromSelectedFiles(e);
            }
```

Comment: If Java is option, you can use `wsgen` to generate a proxy-classes for your service and write small program to test API.

Comment: Do you have some authorization here?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you don't know how to upload image by Postman to remote service?

1. Open postman and choose POST method from address bar.
2. Enter valid URL.
3. Go to **Body** section below address bar.
4. From **Body** section choose **Binary** option. Binary option allows to send things such as images, audio, video and other files.

Please visit [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests) official documentation for more info about how to execute requests. You will more interested in **binary** section which explains uploading.